# Concatenate strings only if they aren't NA values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to concatunate 4 string variables in a pandas dataframe. The dataframe is something like this:

```
Morada 1                            Morada 2        Localidade               Postal Code
RUA DOS QUATRO CAMINHOS VEREDA 2    N 14 4DTO SUL   CANIDELO                 4400-501
RUA DOS QUATRO CAMINHOS VEREDA 2    N 14 4DTO SUL   CANIDELO                 4400-501
Rua chieiras n543 2.9B                              Vila Nova de Gaia        4400-415
RUA BOMBEIROS VOLUNTÁRIOS DECOIM    BRÕES 202 CASA3 Vila Nova de Gaia        4400-057
R DA BELGICA 2387                                   Vila Nova de Gaia        4400-053
```

I'm trying to get to something like this, for instance, for the first line of varibles

```
RUA DOS QUATRO CAMINHOS VEREDA 2 N 14 4DTO SUL CANIDELO 4400-501
```

On the other hand, for line 3, where the variable 'Morada 2' is missing, the goal is to get this:

```
Rua chieiras n543 2.9B Vila Nova de Gaia 4400-415
```

Within the data frame, each one of this 4 variables could be missing, e.g., could be a NA value. My goal is to concatenate the strings by ignoring the ones that are NA.

I was wondering if there is a way of doing this that doesn't involve going through all the possible if conditions of missing values.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just stack and join? eg: `df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine the `DataFrame` using a lambda like my example below:

```
df['combined'] = df.apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
```

This will create a new column for you with combined strings joined, ignoring missing values.